# How to add custom buttons to DataGridView with Entity Framework in .NET Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, datagridview, datasource

I am developing a .NET Windows Forms application. Frankly, I am absolute beginner to .NET windows forms. But I am ASP.NET developer. I am  on my first windows forms project. Now I am having a problem with binding data to DataGridView using Entity Framework. I want to add two custom button columns. But I do not know how to do it since I am absolute beginner to Windows Forms controls.

My code is below:

```
            RestaurantContext context = new RestaurantContext();
            var dbFoods = context.Foods;
            List<FoodMenuRow> rows = new List<FoodMenuRow>();
            foreach(var food in dbFoods)
            {
                FoodMenuRow row = new FoodMenuRow
                {
                    FoodId = food.Id,
                    FoodEnName = food.EnName,
                    FoodMmName = food.MmName,
                    IsAvailable = food.Available
                };
                rows.Add(row);
            }

            dataGridFoodMenu.DataSource = rows;
```

As you can see, I load data from database, then assign value to object, FoodMenuRow to bind data. Because I don't want to bind directly to Entity of EF.

This is the definition if class FoodMenuRow

```
 public class FoodMenuRow
    {
        public int FoodId { get; set; }
        public string FoodMmName { get; set; }
        public string FoodEnName { get; set; }
        public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    }
```

When I run my code, I got something like this:

[image]

But I want to add two extra columns at the end. Both added columns will contain a button each. Then I set event for each button. Buttons something like "Edit" and "Delete". Their logic will be so complicated. I don't want to bind directly from database. I just want to bind with objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The posted code looks odd in the sense that it appears to be making a list of food items when it is not necessary. Following the code... is getting the data from `RestaurantContex` whatever that may be. The variable `dbFoods` is obviously a list or Data Table of these food items. It is difficult to say what type of structure is returned. Whatever it is the code loops through this list/table and creates a new `FoodMenuRow` object with the appropriate properties set. Then this `FoodMenuRow` is added to the `rows` list. This looks unnecessary since it appears you could possibly use `dbFoods` itself as a `DataSource` to `dataGridFoodMenu`. After the `rows` list is filled it is added as a `DataSource` to `dataGridFoodMenu`.

Since the two buttons you described “Edit” and “Delete” would not actually be part of the data in `gataGridFoodMenu` you can add these button columns after the grid is filled like below.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn buttonColEdit = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
buttonColEdit.Name = "Edit";
buttonColEdit.Text = "Edit";
buttonColEdit.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
DataGridViewButtonColumn buttonColDelete = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
buttonColDelete.Name = "Delete";
buttonColDelete.Text = "Delete";
buttonColDelete.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

dataGridFoodMenu.Columns.Add(buttonColEdit);
dataGridFoodMenu.Columns.Add(buttonColDelete);
```

The added buttons should display like below.

[image]

Once the buttons have been added to the `dataGridFoodMenu` the only thing left is to capture when they have been clicked. The `dataGridFoodMenu` event  `CellContentClick` is one event that will allow you to capture when these buttons have been clicked. Looking at the above picture the “Edit” column is in column 4 and the “Delete” column is in column 5. When the `CellContentClick` event is fired a check can be made to see if one of the button columns was clicked and perform the necessary “Edit” or “Delete”.

```
private void dataGridFoodMenu_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 4) { 
    MessageBox.Show("EDIT button clicked at row: " + e.RowIndex);
  }
  else {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 5) {
      MessageBox.Show("DELETE button clicked at row: " + e.RowIndex);
    }
    else {
      // buttons not clicked - ignoring
      //MessageBox.Show("Button cells were not clicked -- row: " + e.RowIndex + " Column: " + e.ColumnIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

I am hoping this may help.